# I want to uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 LTS completely and install windows 8

Tags: uninstall

I want to uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and install windows 8 pro.  I have the Windows disc but an unsure if there is anything special that I need to do first.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No. Just install Windows as if Ubuntu wasn't there.

Note that you will lose everything. Don't forget to backup your important files first.